# Calculate Total Runs For Each Over and I Also Want Sum of First and Second Over. Table Structure is Given Below

Tags: sql, oracle

**Source Table: - Cricket_Scores
**

| Over | Balls | Runs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 | 0 |

**And I Want Output Should be Like Below: -**

| Over | Runs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 25 |

10 Runs: - (Total Runs of first 6 balls which makes an One over) and
25 Runs: - (Total Runs of first 6 balls + Second 6 balls)

**OR**

Something Like Below: -

| Over | Runs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |

10 Runs: -  (Total Runs of first 6 balls which makes an One over) and
15 Runs: -  (Total Runs of Second 6 balls)

How to Write a Query In Oracle/SQL Developer.

Comment: Please provide your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` the `over`s and `SUM` the `runs` to get the runs-per-over:

```sql
SELECT over,
       SUM(runs) AS runs_per_over
FROM   cricket_scores
GROUP BY over
```

Then use an analytic function to get the running total:

```sql
SELECT over,
       SUM(SUM(runs)) OVER (ORDER BY over) AS total_runs
FROM   cricket_scores
GROUP BY over
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cricket_scores( Over, Balls, Runs ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 6, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 5, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 6, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| OVER | TOTAL_RUNS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 25 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-tNWF--j)